# Can't Deploy Go app Error 422 to AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Suddenly can't deploy Go app to GAE.  Haven't changed any of the code and Works fine on local.

03:39 PM Error 422: --- begin server output ---
Compile failed:
2016/10/14 12:39:46 go-app-builder: Failed parsing input: package main must be the top-level package
--- end server output ---

Since it's a cloud app I don't have a Main package - everything was fine a few days ago. I'm on Windows 10 and got and update a few days ago...
I did update to the latest Go Cloud SDK but get the same error.

Comment: Can you include the command your running to deploy?

Comment: goapp deploy 
A Cloud support tech did reply that there is an "ongoing issue" being investigated.  He ask me to run this command: 
gcloud app deploy --verbosity=debug --log-http

...it doesn't run: ERROR: (gcloud) Invalid choice: 'app'. Did you mean 'auth'?
But that doesn't run either...

Comment: I guess the issue is still ongoing.  Support guy said to update GCloud SDK.   I think that it is updated when the GAE Go SDK is updated - isn't it?  Regardless, I don't want to use GCloud because I'd like to keep the same version number & can't figure out how to do that  with GCloud update (because it breaks the advert proxy server that sites in front of my site).  I'm going to have to pay the $125/month for Silver Support - to find out if there is still an ongoing issue & how to work around it.  Let this be a lesson to me.

Comment: uh oh,  it's $150 now and it's kinda messed up too.  It takes you to a support page form that doesn't have a category for GCloud/GAE support.   I sent request to G Suite team and asked them to forward to GCloud...

Comment: yikes!  I submitted a ticket, got response from GSuite who forwarded  it GCloud Support.  Gave me a link and said to post a response to the ticket - but now it has vanished!   Hope I hear from GCloud support anyway.

Comment: Support is unable to tell me when this sdk version will be released.  I am still unable to update my site.   It's been down 3 weeks now.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any non-imported subdirectories in your app directory that may contain package main? I've jumped to the conclusion that go-app-builder is applying the equivalent of go tool vet ./... (instead of go tool vet .) and is using an old version. I recently started encountering this error while deploying:

```
01:05 PM Error 422: --- begin server output ---
Compile failed:
2016/10/19 10:05:23 go-app-builder: Failed parsing input (2 errors)
2016/10/19 10:05:23 appleasn1.go:16:25: composite struct literal encoding/asn1.ObjectIdentifier with unkeyed fields
2016/10/19 10:05:23 appleasn1.go:17:25: composite struct literal encoding/asn1.ObjectIdentifier with unkeyed fields
--- end server output ---
01:05 PM Rolling back the update.
```

asn1.ObjectIdentifier is an alias for []int, so this is not a composite struct literal. This [bug in vet was fixed six months ago](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/9171). I shared my findings with GCloud Support, and they've assured me they're on it. As a workaround, I've made my code pass the overly strict go vet process. If you have a subdirectory in your app that contains package main, you can exclude it in your app.yaml with a skip_files directive:

```
skip_files:
- bench/.*
- testdata/.*
```

The fix for the composite error involved changing from this:

```
oidData = asn1.ObjectIdentifier{1, 2, 840, 113549, 1, 7, 1}
```

to this:

```
oidData = asn1.ObjectIdentifier([]int{1, 2, 840, 113549, 1, 7, 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED:**

This issue stems from App Engine Standard's new ability for apps to provide their own main package with a main function, as explained in our public [Google Groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-go/zL4uLQfVS7c). The workaround is to add `nobuild_files: commands/.*` to your 'app.yaml'.  The official fix for this will be release in the next SDK 1.9.47.

In the meantime, if you have a 'main.go' file, ensure that it is in the same directory level from where you are deploying (aka the top-level package). Also ensure that you are providing the required `appengine.Main()` within your main function as explained in the [source code](https://github.com/golang/appengine/blob/8d4b9e99ddd83f9654e3347a58ba925d3f8a4d10/appengine.go#L35).

I also recommend adding in `// +build !appengine` at the top of your 'main.go' as shown in the [helloworld](https://github.com/golang/appengine/blob/78199dcb0669fc381c22e919e1e97eba879e8f60/demos/helloworld/helloworld.go#L6) example. This will tell App Engine to skip trying to upload or compile any unused code, which may also be the cause of the deployment failure.

Comment: the current version number of the sdk is 1.9.40 - it's complaining that "top level main package is forbidden"  as I try to update my code.

Comment: I noticed in the source code the line "// Main is not yet supported on App Engine Standard."     What's with the spazzy release?  Why no backward compatibility?   Why do this in such a way that I haven't been able to update my site in over a week?

Comment: @JackScheper The comment about _"Main is not yet supported on App Engine Standard"_ in the source is exactly what this [new change](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-go/zL4uLQfVS7c) is correcting. 

Have you followed the list of provided solutions from our Groups post linked above?  Ensuring that all of your imports are from the GOPATH, and that you have added the recommended `nobuild_files: commands/.*` to your 'app.yaml' will ensure that you have the fix in place.

Our upcoming 1.9.46 SDK release will have these fixes implemented for you.

Comment: I understand that this change will correct this difference but that's no reason to suddenly break a process.  It's been 3 weeks!

Comment: @JackScheper Our engineering team has provided an updated ETA. The fix should land in 1.9.47 [SDK](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/release-notes), which should release within the next two weeks. I have updated the above answer to be more complete.